# "artisan make:controller" not creating controller in folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am creating a controller in laravel inside one folder called `Admin` but it just creating `AdminAdminContoller`, using this command

```
artisan make:controller Admin\AdminController --resource
```

To to create folder `Admin` and then `AdminController` inside that folder ?

Comment: working fine on my local machine, just tested

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try

```
php artisan make:controller Admin\\AdminController --resource
```

It will create the `AdminController` in `Admin` folder.

You can also use `--plain` or `--resource` to generate your desired Controller.

```
php artisan make:controller Admin\\AdminController --resource
```

> The backslash (\) character is used to mark special characters
>   so that they are not interpreted by the shell. so Adding another backslash (\) will escape the second backslash (\).

In some terminals below command can also work.

```
php artisan make:controller Admin/AdminController --resource
```

You can find more about backslash (\) [here](https://www.shellscript.sh/escape.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: Explanation: backslash is an escape character in quite some shells, so you need to escape it with another backslash. It should also work to put the path and filename in quotes, though: `php artisan make:controller "Admin\AdminController"`

Comment: One more interesting fact is that adding a  single backslash (\\) will not work on SO too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use slash instead of the double backslash.

```
php artisan make:controller Admin/AdminController --resource
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `php artisan admin:make` command to generate a controller for your 'Package' model in Laravel. Here's how:

Run the following command:

```bash
php artisan admin:make PackageController --model='App\Models\Package'
```

Note:

1. `admin:make` is the command for generating admin panels in Laravel.
2. `PackageController` is the name of the controller you want to create.
3. `--model='App\Models\Package'` specifies the model class that the controller will be associated with.